# matautocomplete panel is causing alignment issues with other fields

Tags: angular, alignment, panel, spfx, mat-autocomplete

Issue is occurring in a SharePoint online UI page which is developed using angular integrated with SPFx.
There is a matautocomplete panel field and its having values overlapped with other fields as shown in picture.
Please suggest any solution as i am new to this.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/THXLU.png)

Please help to rectify this alignment issues with other fields.